# Efficiency of STL algorithms with fixed size arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

In general, I assume that the STL implementation of any algorithm is at least as efficient as anything I can come up with (with the additional benefit of being error free). However, I came to wonder whether the STL's focus on iterators might be harmful in some situations.

Lets assume I want to calculate the inner product of two fixed size arrays. My naive implementation would look like this:

```
std::array<double, 100000> v1;
std::array<double, 100000> v2;
//fill with arbitrary numbers

double sum = 0.0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    sum += v1[i] * v2[i];
}
```

As the number of iterations and the memory layout are known during compile time and all operations can directly be mapped to native processor instructions, the compiler should easily be able to generate the "optimal" machine code from this (loop unrolling, vectorization / FMA instructions ...).

The STL version

```
double sum = std::inner_product(cbegin(v1), cend(v1), cbegin(v2), 0.0);
```

on the other hand adds some additional indirections and even if everything is inlined, the compiler still has to deduce that it is working on a continuous memory region and where this region lies. While this is certainly possible in principle, I wonder, whether the typical c++ compiler will actually do it.

**So my question is**: Do you think, there can be a performance benefit of implementing standard algorithms that operate on fixed size arrays on my own, or will the STL Version always outperform a manual implementation?

Comment: I'd be horrified if any compiler failed to optimize this case as you say, and would consider it a bug in the compiler.  Use the standard algorithms.

Comment: Also a simple way to answer your question is to compile both code and compare the assembly.

Comment: @hivert I did that and VS2013 produces different assembler code. However, as reading assembler is really not my strong suite I cannot say, wheter it is "equivalent"

Comment: Why not actually time the two pieces of code, and see if there's any noticeable difference?

Comment: iterators do not stop the compiler from knowing the size of the range: end-begin. The important thing is to turn on compiler optimizations (on VS, use Release).

Comment: @Igor is right: when it comes to performance, **you always need to time/profile the code**. Guessing about performance is useless.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I finally remembered to post my results here. Do you want to write the bug report or should I ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I did some measurements and

- for the code below
- compiled with VS2013 for x64 in release mode
- executed on a Win8.1 Machine with an i7-2640M,

the algorithm version is **consistently slower by about 20%** (15.6-15.7s vs 12.9-13.1s). The relative difference, also stays roughly constant over two orders of magnitude for `N` and `REPS`.

So I guess the answer is: **Using standard library algorithms CAN hurt performance.**

It would still be interesting, if this is a general problem or if it is specific to my platform, compiler and benchmark. You are welcome to post your own resutls or comment on the benchmark.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

#define USE_STD_ALGORITHM

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

static const size_t N = 10000000; //size of the arrays
static const size_t REPS = 1000; //number of repitions

array<double, N> a1;
array<double, N> a2;

int main(){
    srand(10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        a1[i] = static_cast<double>(rand())*0.01;
        a2[i] = static_cast<double>(rand())*0.01;
    }

    double res = 0.0;
    auto start=high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t z = 0; z < REPS; z++) {     
        #ifdef USE_STD_ALGORITHM
            res = std::inner_product(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin(), res);        
        #else           
            for (size_t t = 0; t < N; ++t)  {
                res+= a1[t] * a2[t];
            }
        #endif        
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << res << "  "; // <-- necessary, so that loop isn't optimized away
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count() <<" ms"<< std::endl;

}
/* 
 * Update: Results (ubuntu 14.04 , haswell)
 * STL: algorithm
 * g++-4.8-2    -march=native -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp               : 1.15287e+24  3551 ms
 * g++-4.8-2    -march=native -std=c++11 -ffast-math -O3 main.cpp   : 1.15287e+24  3567 ms
 * clang++-3.5  -march=native -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp               : 1.15287e+24  9378 ms
 * clang++-3.5  -march=native -std=c++11 -ffast-math -O3 main.cpp   : 1.15287e+24  8505 ms
 *
 * loop:
 * g++-4.8-2    -march=native -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp               : 1.15287e+24  3543 ms
 * g++-4.8-2    -march=native -std=c++11 -ffast-math -O3 main.cpp   : 1.15287e+24  3551 ms
 * clang++-3.5  -march=native -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp               : 1.15287e+24  9613 ms
 * clang++-3.5  -march=native -std=c++11 -ffast-math -O3 main.cpp   : 1.15287e+24  8642 ms
 */
```

EDIT:
I did a quick check with g++-4.9.2  and clang++-3.5 with `O3`and `std=c++11` on a fedora 21 Virtual Box VM on the same machine and apparently those compilers don't have the same problem (the time is almost the same for both versions). However, gcc's version is about twice as fast as clang's (7.5s vs 14s).

Comment: I reproduced your results in VS 12.0.31101 U4, the manual code is ~23% faster, when I did five std tests, five manual tests, then five std again in the same program, and compared the fastest times: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3588921ff5082ddc  In GCC 4.9.2, the std algorithm is ~3% _faster_. My math isn't good enough to determine margin-of error, but the difference is more than triple the stddev of my measurements. In clang 3.5.0, the std is 1.5% faster, almost 2 stddev difference.

Comment: For those curious, my Visual Studio assembly is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/157812e0a373cb2c.  They're very very similar.  I've marked different lines with four hyphens in the middle.  The std code uses `movsd` and `lea` and `addsd`, wheras the for loop uses `movupd` and `mulpd` and `addpd`.  I don't know what those are though.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thanks for the feedback. The windows results are really disappointing. I've to admit that I didn't have a close enough look at the results to see whether the std version is faster on Linux or not. I'll have to do a few more tests on a native linux machine and  VS2015, when Ive the time. See you in another year.

Comment: My gcc/clang tests were on linux.  The Visual Studio code makes no library calls at all, which makes me strongly suspect OS makes no difference at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Sorry if that wasn't clear, I used Windows and Visual Studio as well as Gcc/clang and Linux interchangeably. Although I tend to agree with you that the OS itself doesn't make a difference, I'm not 100% certain, that there are not any relevant differences in how they handle stack memory.